# Apache mod_rewrite by status code not url

Tags: apache, google-search-appliance

This should be basic but having google'd I can't find any similar examplew.

Can I create an Apache rewrite rule that changes all 304 status codes to 404, without changing the url? Our problem is when a page is unpublished on our intranet the Aplaws CMS displays a user friendly 'page not found' message but returns a 304, and our Google Mini box will only remove urls from search results which return a 404.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of this

```
ErrorDocument 304 /errors/304.php
```

/errors/304.php

```
<?php header("Status: 404 Not Found"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that scibuff. I considered something similar but I assumed ErrorDocument directive would only be invoked if it got a 400x or 500x code. Worth a try though I guess.